# Results not Proper for a Full Text Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, database-performance, containstable

I am using CONTAINS for searching a string on a table which has a FULL-TEXT INDEX on name
Table Structure:

```
METADATATAG ( IagID INT (IDENTITY) Name NVARCHAR(500)) 

DECLARE @Contains   nvarchar (1000)
SET @Contains = N'173 57' 
SET @Contains = '"' + @Contains + '*"'

SELECT  *
FROM    MetadataTag MT
WHERE   contains(MT.Name,@Contains)
order by  name
```

The above query results in number of items which has "173 057", 
but which I actually searched for "173 57".

How can I restrict the results for "173 057". It is getting results for even 0 in the string "173 57" Like '173 057'.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Neutral language for Word Breaker in your Full Text Catalog.

Also it would be useful to see result sets for these queries:

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser ('"173 57"', <your language id>, <stop-list id>, 0)

select * from sys.dm_fts_parser ('"173 057"', <your language id>, <stop-list id>, 0)
```